How to listen for ID3 Data With Video.js HLS
I am trying to listen for id3 metadata on videojs.
This is what i tried.
listenForID3MetaData(){
          this.videojsPlayer.textTracks().on('addtrack', e=>{
              var track = e.track;

                  track.on('cuechange', function () {
                      var myActiveCue = track.activeCues[0];
                      console.log(myActiveCue) // cant find data inside this
                      if (myActiveCue && 'frame' in myActiveCue && myActiveCue.frame !== undefined) {
                          let cueDataObj = myActiveCue.frame;
                      }
                  });
              
          });
      }

cue change repeatedly fires but When i add id3 to the stream, i cannot find my text data inside any of the cues. (printed track.activeCues)
If i use Hls.js i can get the id3 metada fine with
 hls.on(Hls.Events.FRAG_PARSING_METADATA, function (event, data) {
      
              var strMessage = new  TextDecoder().decode(data.samples[0].data);

        console.log('event =====> ', event, 'data =====> ', strMessage)
    });

So how can i do the same thing with videojs?
I am using this:
https://github.com/videojs/video.js
not this:
https://github.com/videojs/http-streaming
